# Refactoring to make a function reusable with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make this function reusable but I don't understand how `setState` will be passed to be available in it

```
function getRandomEmployee(updateStateFn){
      const filteredEmployee = employeeList.filter(image => image.hasImage === true)
      const random = filteredEmployee[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredEmployee.length)]
      const randomOpt1 = filteredEmployee[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredEmployee.length)]
      const randomOpt2 = filteredEmployee[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredEmployee.length)]
      const randomOpt3 = filteredEmployee[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredEmployee.length)]
      const randomOptions = [random.fullName, randomOpt1.fullName, randomOpt2.fullName, randomOpt3.fullName]
      randomOptions.sort(() => { return 0.5 - Math.random() })
    setState(state => {
      const newState = updateStateFn && updateStateFn(state)
      return {...newState, randomEmployee: random, randomOptions: randomOptions, playerIsWin:'', disableFieldset: false}
    })
  }
```

I expect the function to output random 4 names and return new states on setState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed a few things here:

1) You have some repetitive code -> `filteredEmployee[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredEmployee.length)]` It would be a good idea to abstract it out. You could do this like:

```js
function getRandomIndex(dataArray) => dataArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * dataArray.length)]
```

Then you could just call the function like: `const randomOption = this.getRandomIndex(filteredEmployee)`

2) For your setState to work, it depends on where this method of yours is located. Is it inside of the component that is handling the state? If it's not, one option is to have your `getRandomEmployee` simply return the object you need and have the component invoking it setState instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would make this function pure and use it when you need to generate these random names, e.g.

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const {random, randomOptions} = getRandomEmployee()
        this.setState({
           randomOptions,
           random,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not true, you can use class components in react 16.8-alpha.1